# Debugging WebApi in Visual Studio returns no response to MVC app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-debugging, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi and MVC5 app within the same solution. When I debug these the MVC5 app calls through to the WebApi fine, however it receives no response.

Using exactly the same code and data with a Console App instead of an MVC5 app then the response comes back fine.

In the mvc app no HTTP response is ever returned. I have debugged the code and the call comes through into the web-api.

The code i'm working with is similar to below, where I'm calling DoMyPost(). No response is returned from  await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);

```
    public MyModel DoMyPost(ModelIN model)
    {
        return PostAsJsonAsync("url", model).Result;
    }

    protected async Task<MyModel> PostAsJsonAsync(string url, ModelIN model)
    {
        var response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
        return await ReadMyModel(response);
    }
```

Any thoughts as to what could be going wrong?

I'm on a windows 8 machine.

===EDIT

I fire up both the MVC5 and web-api app
I debug the MVC 5 app and see it make the call through the code I've outlined above
The break point is hit within the web-api and I can step through until the response is generated.
Then the MVC 5 app sits waiting and never appears to get any response.

I've replace the MVC5 app with a console app, and it receives the response fine.

Thank you

==THE FIX

changing the code to below fixed the issue

```
public MyModel DoMyPost(ModelIN model)
    {
         var response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model).Result;
     return ReadMyModel(response).Result;
    }

    protected async Task<MyModel> PostAsJsonAsync(string url, ModelIN model)
    {
        var response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
        return await ReadMyModel(response);
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Which method are you calling that you are trying to debug?  The MVC5 or WebAPi?

Comment: see my edit to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to try and guess what's going on here.  It looks like you are making a synchronous call to the MVC5 method, "DoMyPost", and then trying to return an Asynchronous result in the PostAsJsonAsync.

I think you should think about exactly what you need to happen and why.  Here is good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087513/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-async-with-mvc5) on using async in MVC5.

Also, [here](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/147201-asp-net-web-api/suggestions/2679733-clean-the-system-web-mvc-and-system-web-http-seoar) is a quick and dirty explanation of the differences between MVC5 and WebApi.  See bottom comment.